# mod_rewrite, trailing slashes - one line instead of two?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been playing with mod_rewrite using .htaccess to translate some directories - for purposes of both improved SEO and also to produce friendlier/more memorable URLs.

The only problem I can't crack at the moment is with trailing slashes.  The behavoir I want is that you should be able to access the link with or without a trailing slash, just to cut down on missed traffic.

My real url is as:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/shipyard/index.php
```

I would like people to be able to access it via:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/shipyard/ 
http://www.mydomain.com/shipyard
http://www.mydomain.com/ships/ 
http://www.mydomain.com/ships
```

Of course, the top two are covered because thats actually a real and accessible URL, but I plan to tell Google that the best way to get at the page is using /ships (without having to move directories, break existing links etc).

The best I came up with so far was:

```
RewriteRule ^ships/$ /shipyard/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ships$ /shipyard/index.php [L]
```

However I just KNOW that i'm using two lines where only one is needed, but whatever I tried, I couldn't get the one!  I know i'm missing something incredibly basic and/or obvious, but I need a pointer...  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^ships(/)?$ /shipyard/index.php [L]
```

This means that the slash may or may not be present.

Comment: When I use that line I just get a 404 error when I don't add the trailing slash...

Comment: Its a hobby project I put up two years ago, I use it for trying out new techniques since its not for a paying customer.  I'm just giving it a much needed redesign, a new feature or two and a bit of SEO.  Feel free to have a look - http://www.potbs-companion.net

Comment: very good site...very fast to browse I must say. clean design. keep it up. :)